# Renaming object properties based on generic parameter within generic context

Tags: typescript

Excuse the long posting, I'm not quite sure how to break it down into a smaller example. Hopefully interesting.

### The Goal

I'm creating a set of helpers to help me interact with a database. I want to specify the columns much like how "RunTypes" does it. e.g. something like this:

```
const SomeTable = Table({
  id: Auto(),
  name: Text(),
  description: Text(),
  value: Number() 
})
```

I have a few goals with this approach.

1. From column types extract "system" and "user" columns, system columns are things like primary keys, which the user (API client) does not provide. "user" columns are the data the user actually wants to store.
2. From column types extract usable underlying TS/JS types. e.g. if a column is Integer, or Text, then this should map to underlying "number" and "string" types.
3. Combining 1 & 2, I should be able to generate an insert() method that extracts types of user columns, so user just needs to provide what is needed and TS type system enforces this.
4. I want to be able to create "groups" of tables behind a facade that interoperate to achieve a certain goal. That goal isn't that important, but what is is that you end up with a table that is the main table for an entity and you have lots of other tables supporting the main table. These support tables will have a foreign key relation to the main table.
5. Given that these groups will be created for a multitude of entities, I need a way to rename the Foreign Key properties of the supporting tables, whilst also interacting with their API in a generic way.

1-4 are relatively easy, where I'm having difficulty is with 5.

### Full Code

See https://codesandbox.io/s/renaming-object-properties-lwcvt?file=/src/index.ts

### Table Definition

See inline comments for commentary.

```
// Define Value Type:
enum ValType {
  SYSTEM = "system", // Implies managed automatically by framework
  USER = "user", // Data is supplied by user
}

// Simple Column Definition type, allows us to recover underlying scalar type for columns
// as well as the value type.
type ColDef<T, TValType extends ValType> = {
  valType: TValType;
  identity(value: any): T;
};

type ColumnMap = { [name: string]: ColDef<any, any> };

// Mapping type to extract System Columns
type SystemColumns<TColumns extends ColumnMap> = {
  [K in keyof TColumns as TColumns[K]["valType"] extends ValType.SYSTEM ? K : never]: TColumns[K];
};

// Mapping type to extract User Columns
type UserColumns<TColumns extends ColumnMap> = {
  [K in keyof TColumns as TColumns[K]["valType"] extends ValType.USER ? K : never]: TColumns[K];
};

// Mapping type to extract underlying Row Type given ColumnMap
type RowType<TColumns extends ColumnMap> = {
  [K in keyof TColumns]: ReturnType<TColumns[K]["identity"]>;
};

// Some Column Definition helper functions
const Text = (): ColDef<string, ValType.USER> => ({
  valType: ValType.USER,
  identity(value: any): string {
    return value as string;
  },
});

const Number = (): ColDef<number, ValType.USER> => ({
  valType: ValType.USER,
  identity(value: any): number {
    return value as number;
  },
});

const SysNumber = (): ColDef<number, ValType.SYSTEM> => ({
  valType: ValType.SYSTEM,
  identity(value: any): number {
    return value as number;
  },
});

// Test of our helpers
const SomeColumns = {
  id: SysNumber(),
  name: Text(),
  description: Text(),
  value: Number(),
};

// Hover over to see that type extraction functions are working
type SomeColumnsType = typeof SomeColumns;
type SomeColumnsRowType = RowType<typeof SomeColumns>;
type SomeColumnsSystemColumns = RowType<SystemColumns<typeof SomeColumns>>;
type SomeColumnsUserColumns = RowType<UserColumns<typeof SomeColumns>>;
type SomeColumnsValueShouldBeNumber = SomeColumnsUserColumns["value"] // Works
```

### Renaming Columns

The key type here is `RenameForeignKey`. It maps over the column types and replaces all instances of `entityId` with `${TName}Id`.

This works in the trivial case, as is, the `AliceIdType` it correctly infers as a number.

```
// Mapping type to rename an appearance of "entityId" with "${TName}Id", so we can
// specialise Foreign Key for different entities, embedding name into the key column def.
export type RenameForeignKey<TName extends string, TColumns extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof TColumns as K extends "entityId" ? `${TName}Id` : K]: TColumns[K];
};

const SomeColumnsWithFk = {
  id: SysNumber(),
  entityId: Number(),
  tag: Text(),
};

type FkRenamed = RenameForeignKey<"alice", typeof SomeColumnsWithFk>;
type FkRenamedRows = RowType<FkRenamed>;
type FkRenamedSystem = RowType<SystemColumns<FkRenamed>>;

// If you hover the type here, its looking good, we've extracted underlying TS types from the definition,
// derived from a rename.
type FkRenamedUserColumns = RowType<UserColumns<FkRenamed>>;
type AliceIdType = FkRenamedUserColumns["aliceId"];
```

### Creating Specialised Tables

I tried a couple of approaches, first I created a table that renames the FK on the extracted row type, in the insert method. This works.

```
type Input<TEntity extends string, TColumns extends ColumnMap> = RenameForeignKey<
  TEntity,
  RowType<UserColumns<TColumns>>
>;

type Table1<TName extends string, TColumns extends ColumnMap> = {
  name: TName;
  columns: TColumns;
  insert: (values: Input<TName, TColumns>) => void;
};

function createTable1<TEntity extends string, TColumns extends ColumnMap>(
  name: TEntity,
  columns: TColumns
): Table1<TEntity, TColumns> {
  return {
    name,
    columns,
    insert(values: Input<TEntity, TColumns>): void {
      return;
    },
  };
}

const table = createTable1("bob", SomeColumnsWithFk);

table.insert({ bobId: 1, tag: "doh" }); // works!
```

Then I tried creating the table by renaming the columns at point of creation, here I created a `renameFk` function to carry out the renaming, that returns the `RenameForeignKey` type created earlier. Again, this works at the top-level.

```
type Table2<TName extends string, TColumns extends ColumnMap> = {
  name: TName;
  columns: TColumns;
  insert: (values: RowType<UserColumns<TColumns>>) => void;
};

function createTable2<TEntityName extends string, TColumns extends ColumnMap>(
  name: TEntityName,
  columns: TColumns
): Table2<TEntityName, TColumns> {
  return {
    name,
    columns,
    insert(values: RowType<UserColumns<TColumns>>): void {
      return;
    },
  };
}

function renameFk<TName extends string, TAny extends Record<string, any>>(
  name: TName,
  obj: TAny
): RenameForeignKey<TName, TAny> {
  return {
    ...omit(obj as unknown as object, "entityId"),
    [`${this.name}Id`]: obj["entityId"],
  } as unknown as RenameForeignKey<TName, TAny>;
}

const table2 = createTable2("carol", renameFk("carol", SomeColumnsWithFk));
table2.insert({ carolId: 2, tag: "tagged" }); // so far so good
```

### Using Tables in a Generic Context

Now that I've got what seem like a couple of viable approaches, I want to use them in a context where the name of the table is provided as a generic parameter. This example is using a class but same applies to a function.

I'm using `renameFk` to convert the parameters of the insert to the correct fk name, but I can't seem to insert a value that passes the type checker.

```
class Test<TName extends string> {
  name: TName;

  public table1: Table1<TName, typeof SomeColumnsWithFk>;
  public table2: Table2<TName, RenameForeignKey<TName, typeof SomeColumnsWithFk>>;

  constructor(name: TName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.table1 = createTable1(name, SomeColumnsWithFk);
    this.table2 = createTable2(name, renameFk(name, SomeColumnsWithFk));

    const value1 = renameFk(this.name, {
      entityIdasd: 4, // can enter anything nothing complains
      tag: "sometag",
    });

    this.table1.insert(value1);

    const value2 = renameFk(this.name, {
      entityId: 1,
      tag: "doh!",
    });

    this.table2.insert(value2); // Gives an error
  }
}
```

If i access the tables outside, post instantiation, then types work correctly:

```
const test = new Test("eliza");

// This works
test.table1.insert({
  elizaId: 1,
  tag: "stuff",
});

// This works
test.table2.insert({
  elizaId: 1,
  tag: "stuff",
});
```

### The Question

How do I generate values that conform to the renamed foreign key, within the class context (or any generic context)?

### Thanks!

Thanks for bearing with me.